# Exception Tree for sqlite3 in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

Background: I am trying to use a small in-memory database in an application. The table names and columns are specified in a Map, and whether the column is an integer in a List (if not in list, it is text). I can create the connection alright. While trying to invoke the "createStatement()" and "execute()" methods of the Connection, they work fine if wrapped in a try/catch structure. However, if I try to propagate the SQLException up the call hierarchy, eclipse complains of "unhandled exception SQLException". Must be the way I am using the Map. Can someone help me understand what is the difference between the 2 approaches? Thank you.

```
private void createTables () throws SQLException {
    tableColumns.forEach((tableName, columnNames) -> {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",\n");
        for (String colName : columnNames) {
            if (iColNames.contains(colName)) {
                sj.add ("\t" + colName + " integer"); 
            } else {
                sj.add ("\t" + colName + " text not null");
            }
        }
        String sql = "create table " + tableName + "(\n" + sj.toString() + "\n);";
        System.out.println (sql);
        Statement stmt;
//          try {
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute(sql); 
//          } catch (SQLException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }  
        });
    }
```

Here is what is calling the method:

```
public RunIdMap (String dbFileName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFileName);
    createTables ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you are propogating the exception up the call stack, are you handling the exception there?

The exception needs to be handled somewhere , so when you are propogating an exception up the call stack using throws you need to handle the exception at the calling place.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The method is called from main() and there it is caught (as Exception, not SQLException, though)

Comment: PS: I tried catching SQLException explicitly, the problem remains the same. I am wondering if iterating through the hash table in the foreach() loop is creating instance of an anonymous class which is unable to catch or propagate the Exception.

Comment: @ManidipSengupta can you please post the snippet of the calling method where you are handling the exception. because if you are handling it, then error where the compiler asking you to handle it should go away.

Comment: The foreach loop is using an anonymous function, or so-called lambda. By the design/evolution of Java language, these functions are unable to propagate exceptions up the call hierarchy. The problem goes away if I put a try/catch block around the stmt ... calls, and in the catch clause throw a RuntimeException instead. This avoids the compilation problem, but now I have to keep it in my head to catch a RuntimeException. Oh, well!